# Change C++ version

Tags: 14.04, c++, compiler

I am trying to change the C++ compiler version. I have both, 4.6.x AND 4.4 versions, I want to set it to the 4.4 version, so I am doing:

```
export "CXX=g++-4.4"
```

But when I run the command:

```
g++ -v
```

I am still getting this:

```
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I am using this tutorial:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CXX` variable doesn't affect how the shell resolves program name `g++`: that just follows the usual conventions of your executable search path `$PATH`, and is finally determined by a symbolic link e.g. on my 14.04 system

```
$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```

while

```
$ ls -l $(which g++)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  7  2014 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.8
```

If you want to change that, you will need to re-make the symbolic link either manually e.g.

```
sudo ln -sf g++-4.4 /usr/bin/g++
```

or using the *update-alternatives* mechanism.

***However***, many build processes will respect the setting of `CXX` (and the equivalent `CC` for the C compiler, `FC` for the Fortran compiler and so on) so that there is often no need to change the default compiler(s) via symlinks: if there is a particular software build that you are having difficulty with then I suggest you post a question about that specifically.